# Python Click: How to change the value of `info_name` for the global context

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing, command-line-interface, python-click

In a Python script using Click for the command line handling, I would like to change the `info_name` in the global context (in order to modify the help output).

Here is a contrived minimal example `mycmd.py` where I try using the `context_settings`:

```
import click

CONTEXT_SETTINGS = dict(info_name="hallo")

@click.command('mycmd', context_settings=CONTEXT_SETTINGS)
@click.pass_context
def click_cli(ctx):
   pass

click_cli()
```

However when I run this script with `python mycmd.py --help` I get the traceback:

```
...
  File ".../click/core.py", line 639, in make_context
    ctx = Context(self, info_name=info_name, parent=parent, **extra)
TypeError: type object got multiple values for keyword argument 'info_name'
```

So the problem is that the arguments in `**extra` (that's where the context_settings end up) cannot overwrite the hard-coded `info_name=info_name` parameter. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `prog_name` parameter for the cli function, to change the help name (`info_name`) like:

```
cli(prog_name='hallo')
```

#### Test Code:

```
import click

@click.command('mycmd')
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    pass

cli(['--help'], prog_name='hallo')
```

#### Results:

```
Usage: hallo [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.
```